# reset non-root user password without using root previleges

Tags: mysql

Is it feasible to reset a normal user's mysql password without using root privileges?

I can login using old password but being a non-root user, can't use mysql table.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is only possible if the normal user has privileges to update `mysql.user` table.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reset other user's password without root privs.

But if you have root access to system running MySQL server, you can start mysql with `--skip-grant-tables`, which would allow you to log in without password as root and so change any password. See here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try mysqladmin, but if you just have common table privileges it probably won't let you do it...

```
mysqladmin -u <USERNAME> -p password <YOUR NEW PASSWORD>
```

It will then ask you for your current password.